# Transfer access rights to the Telegram-channel

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I need to transfer access rights to the Telegram-channel.

I'm trying to do this using the EditCreatorRequest function. But it doesn't work out for me, because I don't understand what parameters need to be specified, namely, I'm stuck on specifying a password. Unfortunately, there is no clear example in the documentation. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the internal function the library uses:

```py
from telethon.password import compute_check
from telethon.tl.functions import account, channels

pass_info = await client(account.GetPasswordRequest())
input_srp = compute_check(
    pass_info, "your_password"
)
await client(
    channels.EditCreatorRequest(
        channel, user,
        password=input_srp
    )
)
```